# Choosing element from array in VHDL

Tags: arrays, indexing, vhdl

I have an component that receives an array:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.index_pkg.all;

entity update_reg is
    port (
    index         : in integer;
    number_data   : in array_integer(9 downto 0);
    output_number : out integer;
);
end update_reg;

architecture behavior of update_reg is
begin
process1 : process(index, number_data)
begin
    output_number <= number_data(index);
end process;    
end architecture;
```

The purpose is to have at the component's output the array's element specified by the index. I built the following tb to test its behaviour:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.index_pkg.all;


entity tb_update_reg is
end tb_update_reg;

architecture rtl of tb_update_reg is

component update_reg is
    port (
    index         : in integer;
    number_data   : in array_integer(9 downto 0);
    output_number : out integer
);
end component;

signal tb_index         : integer;
signal tb_number_data   : array_integer(9 downto 0);
signal tb_output_number : integer; 
begin
fill_process : process(tb_number_data)
begin
    for n in 0 to 9 loop
        tb_number_data(n) <= 10 - n;
    end loop;
end process;
stim_process : process
begin
    tb_index <= 6;
    wait for 2.0 ns;
    tb_index <= 0;
    wait for 2.0 ns;
    tb_index <= 9;
    wait for 2.0 ns;
    tb_index <= 4;
    wait for 2.0 ns;
    tb_index <= 1;
    wait for 2.0 ns;
end process;
upd_reg : update_reg
port map(
    index         => tb_index,
    number_data   => tb_number_data,
    output_number => tb_output_number
);
end architecture;
```

And I added a package where I included the declaration for the array integer:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


package index_pkg is     
type array_integer is array (natural range <>) of integer;
end;
```

I would expect the numbers 4/10/1/6/9. Instead, the simulation is frozen. Is there some aspect I am missing?

I would be grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

i) You need to initialise the signal `tb_index` to 6:

```
signal tb_index         : integer := 6;
```

In VHDL all processes are executed at time 0 right at the start of the simulation. Without such initialisation, this line in your design:

```
output_number <= number_data(index);
```

gets executed before the `index` signal has been given a value by this line:

```
tb_index <= 6;
```

So, on the first *delta cycle* the value of `index` is the default for an integer, the *leftmost value* (-2^31-1), which of course is *out of range*.

ii) You need a wait statement at the bottom of the `stim_process` process:

```
    wait for 2.0 ns;
    wait;
end process;
```

In VHDL all processes loop continuously. So, the `stim_process` process loops back to the top and so your simulation runs forever. `wait;` in VHDL means *wait forever*, which is what you need here.

Also, this line in your design has an extra semicolon:

```
output_number : out integer;
```

it should be:

```
output_number : out integer
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3JaN